# How would I add / maintain a checksum on a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have some data I need to put into a file, however I want to ensure that the data remains intact. Either from corruption or from a user modifying the file.

Can someone point me in the right direction, of how to add a checksum to a file, read / check the file is correct?

Comment: Anyone, haven't had an exact answer so far ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **`MD5`** hash, that's the best option. Here is how to create a **`MD5` hash from `NSString`, `NSData` or a File**:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html

Comment: Yeap, calculate the MD5 hash, store/send your data. Then, calculate the MD5 hash again. If these two hashes are not the same that will mean that the data is corrupted or someone modified it.

Comment: OK :) Erm, does MD5 come under the heading of encryption and therefore that I may have issues with permission with the App Store rules ?

Comment: No, you won't have any problems with that. MD5 does not encrypt your data. I submitted to the App Store several apps where I use MD5 hashes without any problems.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Please add some content of the linked site here because this link could be dead someday.